# Is it good that they closed a question with more upvotes than downvotes, and 3 "favourite question" marks?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

My question received 3 "favourite question" marks for the first 3 hours after it was published.

On the other hand, Stack Overflow is flooded with questions like: "below is my code, why doesn't it work?" or "please do my exercise instead of me", and it seems nobody cares much, and nobody closes them.  But they closed my question: [Why is Algol dead, and Fortran isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230674/why-is-algol-dead-and-fortran-isnt) :

[image]

It seems any question which is slightly non-standard ( = not boring) attracts attention, and is being closed.  If anyone could vote both for and against closing my question, I guess 5 people would vote "for", and about 10 people would vote "against".

Reopen can be done only after the question was closed, not before.

Comment: if it isn't on topic, absolutely. A question can be useful, interesting, and off topic/too broad etc, all at the same time.

Comment: Users often mark as favourite as a notice to come back to the question at a later stage to see if you have listened to their advice provided in comments or to see if any changes have been made to the question which has brought it _on-topic_. I'm not saying this is the case here but it's a possibility.

Comment: Who's this "they" you speak of? I think the pronoun you're looking for is "we", since you too can vote to close questions. You can vote to reopen as well. This question is unlikely to be reopened because it's blatantly off-topic (nothing to do with its "boringness" or lack thereof).

Comment: You are right we keep too many "do my work for me" questions. That doesnt mean we should accept everything. This is truly off topic for Stack, and was rightfully closed. The fact it was interesting doesn't change that

Comment: _Is it good that they closed a question **with more upvotes than downvotes**, and 3 “favourite question” marks?_ - By now you're a victim of  the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: OT: please stop with rhetorical questions. Your title should have been: "My question was wrongfully closed". And, when you put it that way - may be you'd hesitate to post...

Comment: @Who's this "they" you speak of? I think the pronoun you're looking for is "we", since you too can vote to close questions.  - I cannot vote to close *my* question.

Comment: @user31264 well seems like I do have access to close my own question. I didn't get the dialog box to the end, because I don't want to cast a real CTV on my only question, but it does seem doable (also, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37752/how-do-i-close-my-own-question)

Answer (score 30):

> My question received 3 "favourite question" marks for the first 3 hours after it was published.

This is most likely because 3 users starred your question. There are many reasons to do this, but a question receiving stars has no bearing on how on-topic the question is.

> On the other hand, stackoverflow is flooded with question "below is my code, why doesn't it work?" or "please do my excersize instead of me", and it seems nobody cares much, and nobody closes them.

Without actual examples, not much can be said. Basically you're saying that there are lots of debugging style questions and how-to style questions that are not closed. This is true. There are also lots of debugging style questions and how-to style questions that *are* closed, so this observation is meaningless.

> But they closed my question: [Why is Algol dead, and Fortran isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43230674)

Just from the title alone I can tell that the question is primarily opinion based. Answers to your question may have some references to facts, but they are generally going to be based primarily on opinions. Questions like this have been deemed to be off-topic and not useful for furthering the goal of the site.

> It seems any question which is slightly non-standard ( = not boring) attracts attention, and is being closed.

I completely disagree. There are plenty of on-topic practical programming questions asked every day that are interesting. The problem is finding them through all of the off-topic or low quality questions that users insist on posting.

> If anyone could vote both for and against closing my quesion, I guess 5 people would vote "for", and about 10 people would vote "against".

There is an option to vote against closing your question. It is called the reopen vote system. If users feel that the question was closed incorrectly, they can vote to reopen it. It only takes five reopen votes to reopen a question. As your question is still closed, I don't think your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Users star/favourite questions for all sorts of different reasons. Some do so in order to remember to go back to delete vote a question once it has garnered enough close votes to be closed so I wouldn't count the presence of favourites as meaning that those users either liked the question or found it useful.

Comment: Totally agree. My favorite reason to favorite a question is to make sure it gets closed/deleted... As the only built-in way of creating a list of questions it is more likely to be used for reasons far from "this is question I like".